# Make this regular expression shorter

Tags: php, regex

I was wondering whether it is possible to simplify a regular expression like this one

```
/^[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}$/
```

into something shorter

something like

```
/^([([0-9]{2})([ .-]?))]{4})[0-9]$/
```

but I don't seem to get it right, nor even getting close to figuring it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex:

```
/^[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}[ .-]?[0-9]{2}$/
```

can be shortened to:

```
/^(?:[0-9]{2}[ .-]?){4}[0-9]{2}$/
```

Comment: Which, in PHP, and if you're not interested in capturing groups, can be shortened to `/^(\d\d[ .-]?){4}\d\d$/`.

Comment: @acheong87: Since OP wasn't capturing anything I used `(?:...)` to avoid a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this:

```
^([0-9]{2}[ .-]?){5}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

It's a lot shorter but will also match `11-11-11-11-11-`. The exact equivalent is posted by @anubhava.

You original regex looks like this:
[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: `11.11.11.11.11.` passes.

Comment: This will allow a trailing `hyphen OR space OR dot` which isn't allowed by original regex.

Comment: anubhava is right, though I'm wondering about how you got that image representation..